# Error:-E00006 in Authorize.net payment integration in codeigniter

Tags: authorize.net

When I payment through live mode authorize.net give reponse code E00006(The API user name is invalid or not present)
How to resolved it?

Comment: There isn't enough information here. At the very least you need to show your code. Also, did you validate you are using the correct credentials? Are you accidentally using developer credentials in your production environment? Or vice versa?

Comment: Dear John Conde,                                                                                               Thanks for the reply, I am using AuthorizeCimLib codeignitor library.library generate xml when  call function create_customer_profile() .So what should be name & value for proper xml post on the live server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Authorize net in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948603/how-to-use-authorize-net-in-asp-net)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948603/how-to-use-authorize-net-in-asp-net/46953980#46953980)

Answer (score 0):

Check the **name** value of the XML or JSON you are posting.

Be sure you are using the appropriate credentials for the API endpoint you are posting to:
Sandbox URL: https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api
Production URL: https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions.

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions .I am using codeignitor authorize.net library.In library we just set config Login api I'd & transaction I'd.My credential are correct but Authorize.net doesn't accept .If there any requirement for payment activation configration on merchant profile?